# Integration using quadrature

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I have been having a few issues using the quadrature function in python 2.7 (part of the scipy.integrate module). The equation I am trying to integrate is simply:

```
x/(d^2) - (x^2)
```

The integration is between limits a and b. However, I need to do the integration at 40 different values of d and am not sure how to pass in the second argument so as to loop the integration over the values of d. Any help would be much appreciated and is quadrature the best way to evaluate this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [9]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [10]: a = 0

In [11]: b = 1

In [12]: [quad(lambda x, d: x/(d**2)-x**2, a, b, args=d) for d in range(2, 5)]
Out[12]: 
[(-0.20833333333333334, 2.3717550132075781e-15),
 (-0.27777777777777773, 3.0886887822595405e-15),
 (-0.30208333333333337, 3.3546344203581545e-15)]
```

Change the `for d in range(2, 5)` as required.

Answer (score 2):

```
from numpy import arange
from scipy.integrate import quad
beg = 0.
end = 4.
res = []
for d in arange(1., 40.):
    res.append(quad(lambda x: x/(d**2.)-(x**2.), beg, end))
```

You can then access the results by

```
print res[0]
```

or even

```
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact symbolic integration, you'll need to turn to [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html). Try

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
a = sympy.Symbol('a')
b = sympy.Symbol('b')
d = sympy.Symbol('d')

res = sympy.integrate(x / (d**2 - x**2), (x, a, b))
print(res)
```

This returns

```
log(a**2 - d**2)/2 - log(b**2 - d**2)/2
```

which you can most easily use to evaluate your data.